# Insert new column with values from a python list into an existing sql table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

**MY PROBLEM:** I want to create a new column in an existing table with values from a python list. My SQL table looks like this:

```
   gender  age  cholesterol  smoke
        1   13            1      0
        1   45            2      0
        0    1            2      1
```

And I have values in a python list: `new_data = [1,2,3]` I want to create a new column in the SQL table and then populate it with the values in the list. So the final table should look like this:

```
   gender  age  cholesterol  smoke  new_data
        1   13            1      0         1
        1   45            2      0         2
        0    1            2      1         3
```

**SO FAR:** I've tried to create a new column and then try to pass the values:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
curs = con.cursor()
curs.execute('''ALTER TABLE demo ADD COLUMN new_date''')
con.commit()
new_data = [1,2,3]
curs.execute("INSERT INTO demo(new_date) VALUES(?)", new_data))
```

But it doesn’t work and gives this error:

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.
```

What should I do?

Here is the **dump** for the example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'gender' :      [1,  1,  0],
                          'age' :         [13, 45, 1],
                          'cholesterol' : [1,  2,  2],
                          'smoke' :       [0,  0,  1]
                          })
```

Comment: That's not possible - INSERT INTO is for creating new rows not adding data to existing rows.

Comment: So, what function should I use @norie?

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: sqlite3.sqlite_version: 3.33.0 @forpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update the table after you add the new column and not insert new rows.

Instead of the list `new_data = [1,2,3]` pass a list of lists `new_data = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]` with the 2nd item of each list is the row number of the row that will be updated.
So, if you wanted to update the column with the values 100, 150, 250 then `new_data` should be `new_data = [[100, 1], [150, 2], [250, 3]]`.

The `UPDATE` statement will have a `WHERE` clause that will check which row should be updated each time:

```
new_data = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
sql = """
UPDATE demo AS d
SET new_data = ?
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo dd WHERE dd.rowid <= d.rowid) = ?
"""
curs.executemany(sql, new_data)
con.commit()
```

Since your version of SQLite is 3.33.0 you could also use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
sql = """
UPDATE demo AS d1
SET new_data = ?
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowid) rn FROM demo) AS d2
WHERE d2.rowid = d1.rowid AND rn = ?
"""
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw I've updated my SQLite version, syntax is more friendly!